# Are two lifts of a generator of a cyclic quotient conjugated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group and $I$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/I$ is cyclic, and let $\bar{g}$ be a generator. Let $g, g' \in G$ be two lifts of $\bar{g}$, i.e. $g + I = g' + I = \bar{g}$.

**Question**: Are $g$ and $g'$ conjugated, i.e. does there exist an element $h \in G$ such that $g' = hgh^{-1}$?

**Approach**:
If we would have a surjective group homomorphism $\varphi: G \to H$ where $H$ is cyclic, then $G/I \simeq H$ where $I = \ker{\varphi}$. If $\bar{g}$ is a generator of $G/I$ and $g$, $g' \in G$ be two lifts of $\bar{g}$, then $\varphi(m g m^{-1}) = \varphi(g) = \varphi(g')$ for all $m \in I$. So it would be neat if it is possible to find an element $m \in I$ such that $mgm^{-1} = g'$. But I don't know if that is going to be useful or possible.

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: In the general case, no. Just take into account what'd happen if $\;G\;$ is abelian...

Comment: It's not true even for Abelian groups: consider $\pi_2:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ and $(0,1)$ with $(1,1)$.

Comment: What happens with conjugation when $G$ is abelian? Then find a cyclic group that is generated by two distinct elements.

Comment: A better question would be whether they are conjugate in the holomorph of $G$.

Comment: @CMonsour: Oh, I have never heard of the holomorph of a group before. Why would the question become more interesting then?

Comment: @CMonsour Take say $G=S_n$ and $I=A_n$. Then $g$ and $g'$ can be any odd permutations. They may not even have the same order, so they won't be conjugate.